# No indexers created by Djapian for Django

Tags: django, xapian

I am working through the tutorial for setting up Djapian and am trying to use the indexshell (as demonstrated in [this step](http://code.google.com/p/djapian/wiki/Tutorial#Initial_data_and_index_check)). When I run the command 'list' I get the following output:

```
Installed spaces/models/indexers:
- 0: 'global'
```

I therefore cannot run any queries:

```
>>> query
No index selected
```

Which leads me to attempt:

```
>>> use 0
Illegal index alias '0'. See 'list' command for available aliases
```

My index.py is as follows:

```
from djapian import space, Indexer, CompositeIndexer
from cms.models import Article

class ArticleIndexer(Indexer):
    fields = ['body']
    tags = [
        ('title', 'title'),
        ('author', 'author'),
        ('pub_date', 'pub_date',),
        ('category', 'category')
    ]

space.add_index(Article, ArticleIndexer, attach_as='indexer')
```

**Update:** I moved the djapian folder from site-packages to within my project folder and I move index.py from the project root to within the djapian folder. When I run 'list' in the indexshell the following is now returned:

```
>>> list
Installed spaces/models/indexers:
- 0: 'global'
    - 0.0 'cms.Article'
        -0.0.0: 'djapian.space.defaultcmsarticleindexer'
```

I still cannot do anything though as when I try to select an index I still get the following error:

```
>>> use 0.0
Illegal index alias '0'. See 'list' command for available aliases
```

**Update 2:** I had a problem with my setting for DJAPIAN_DATABASE_PATH which is now fixed. I can select an indexer using the command 'use 0.0.0' but when I try to run a query it raises the following ValueError: "Empty slice".

Comment: Did you run "manage.py index --rebuild"?

Comment: I did and I tried re-running it now and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Can you run "list" and paste in the list of your indexes?

Comment: Th results of running 'list' is displayed in the first quote/code block of my post.

Comment: Where do you place this indexer definition? index.py or somewhere else?

Comment: Sorry Pheter, missed that part!

Comment: I've placed the indexer definition within index.py and index.py is located in the project root (along with manage.py and urls.py). Is this is correct location for it?

Comment: Index.py should be placed in an app directory, alongside models.py I've updated my answer with this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you fixed the problem of the ValueError: Empty Slice?

I'm having the exact same problem using the djapian tutorial. First I was wondering if my database entries were right, but now I'm thinking it might have something to do with the actual querying of the Xapian install?

Seeing that I haven't had to point to the install at all wonders me if I placed it in the right directory and if djapian knows where to find it.

-- Edit
I've found the solution, atleast for me. The tutorial is not up to date and the query command expects a number of results too. So if you use 'query mykeyword 5' you get 5 results and the ValueError: Empty Slice disappears. It's a known issue and it will be fixed soon from what I read.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're not loading indexes?

You could try placing the following in your main urls.py:

```
import djapian
djapian.load_indexes()
```

In a comment to your question you write that you've placed index.py file in the project root. It should actually reside within an app, along models.py.

One more thing (which is very unlikely to be the cause of your problems); you've got a stray comma on the following line:

```
('pub_date', 'pub_date',),
                       ^
```

Comment: I was already loading indexes but had overlooked the stray comma. Thanks for pointing it out but unfortunately it didn't solve my problem.